# How to place the tables on different pages in latex?

Tags: latex

I have two tables on one page in latex and I want to have these tables on different pages, the one on this page and the next one on the next page, how can I do it? I used `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}`, but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: *Where* did you use `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}`? Is this page of floats at the end of your document or in the middle? Can you provide us with a minimal example that replicates the problem?

Comment: Please post a [small, compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a page break with `\pagebreak` or `\newpage`.

Comment: but I don't want to have interruption in text.

Comment: How about putting [one of] the tables in a `float` environment to allow it to be repositioned?

Comment: what do you mean by float environment?

Comment: the table is in the table environment \begin{table} [t]

Comment: If they are already floating, you can try either moving the table to a different place in the source or changing the positioning commands in the square brackets (e.g. `[p]` instead of `[t]`)